# classcast exception on spring-data-jpa dto

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am not able to cast JPA ResultSet to DTO. While I am getting Values from Database, but printing values using toString() method, I am getting ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.practice.entity.CityEntity
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.practice.service.CityService.getCities(CityService.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
```

---

```
@Service
public class CityService {
.....

            cityListing = cityDAO.citylisting(countryName);

            cityResponse.setCityCount(cityListing.size());


    cityListing.forEach(s -> {
                System.out.println(s);
                responseCityList.add(s);
            });
```

---

```
@Repository("cityDAO")
public interface CityManipulationDAO extends JpaRepository<CityEntity, Integer>{

    @Query("Select a.id, a.name, a.district,a.countrycode, a.population from CityEntity a where a.countrycode.CountryName=:countryName")
    //List of cities for particular countries
    public List<CityEntity> citylisting(@Param("countryName") String Name);

}

@Entity
@Table(name="city")
public class CityEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="countrycode", referencedColumnName="code")
    private CountryEntity countrycode;

    @Column
    private String district;

    @Column
    private Integer population;
...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return id+","+name+","+district+","+population;
    }
}
```

While Debugging, I found that `cityListing` is getting populated.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: What is the type of `cityListing` and `responseCityList`?

Comment: both are of type `List<CityEntity> cityListing`

Comment: I guess the problem lies where you are returning `a.countrycode` in your query, it is returning an entire CountryEntity object over there.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return a `List<Object[]>`.

```
@Query("Select a.id, a.name, a.district,a.countrycode, a.population from CityEntity a where a.countrycode.CountryName=:countryName")
//List of cities for particular countries
public List<CityEntity> citylisting(@Param("countryName") String Name);
```

I believe based off of your stack trace that `responseCityList.add(s);` is attempting to cast `s` to a `CityEntity` and failing.

Please update your query to this.

```
@Query("Select a from CityEntity a where a.countrycode.CountryName=:countryName")
//List of cities for particular countries
public List<CityEntity> citylisting(@Param("countryName") String Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want countrycode to be selected in the my api response.

Comment: There's multiple approaches you can use to do that.  You can process the list after the query to create your own POJOs, you can use the new operator within the query to refer directly to the constructor on your POJO, or you could use an `EntityGraph`.  There's several more to accomplish your goal.